# UITableView as inputAccessoryView has height of zero

Tags: uitableview, ios8, inputaccessoryview

I have two table views that I use as input accessory views in my project. One is created programatically, and displays perfectly well. The second is a custom table view with custom cells made in storyboard and stored as a property of the view controller as a strong reference.

```
@property UITableView *firstTable; @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *secondTable;
```

They are both initiated in viewDidLoad as follows:

```
self.firstTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:
                        CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 100) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.firstTable.delegate = self;
self.firstTable.dataSource = self;
self.firstTable.scrollEnabled = YES;
self.firstTable.rowHeight = 30;
self.firstTable.backgroundColor = [[SwagCommonFunctions alloc] colorWithHexString:@"f4ecea"];

self.secondTable.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 100);
```

They are set as input accessory views in another function

```
[textView setInputAccessoryView:self.firstTableView];
    [textView reloadInputViews];
```

OR

```
[textView setInputAccessoryView:self.secondTableView];
    [textView reloadInputViews];
```

firstTable works perfectly. secondTable is never loaded because frame height is zero at the time of cellForRowAtIndexPath. If the frame height is manually set at 100 (the width is full screen) with origin of (0,0) in numberOfRowsInSection, secondTable appears as expected with the correct data, but the frame obscures the entire keyboard instead of resting in the normal inputAccessoryView location.

How do I set the frame of secondTable to behave correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.secondTable.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
```